# Create customize Loss function for my deep learning model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I am currently working on a deep learning project in the signal processing domain. The currently used loss function is the mean square error (MSE). However, it turns out that this loss function does not directly reflect my evaluation metric. Thus, I decide to use the alternative loss function, named Zero mean Normalization Cross-Correlation (ZNCC).

Note: I use TensorFlow 2.0 for this project

Here is my defined loss function.

```
def ZNCC(true, predict):
  true = true.numpy()
  predict = predict.numpy()
  x_bar = np.average(true)
  y_bar = np.average(predict)
  u = true - x_bar
  v = predict - y_bar

  top = np.dot(u,v)
  bottom = np.linalg.norm(u) * np.linalg.norm(v)
  zncc = top/bottom
  if zncc<0:
    zncc = 0
  return tf.convert_to_tensor(1-zncc)
```

Here is the compilation statement

```
model = MyModel()
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.002,beta_1=0.99,beta_2=0.989,epsilon=1e-07), loss=ZNCC, run_eagerly=True)
```

And here is my `model.fit()` statement

```
history = model.fit(training_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    epochs=150,
                    callbacks=[tensorboard_callback, model_checkpoint_callback])
```

After I run the above cell, I run into this error.

```
Epoch 1/150
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-142-c047e0d40ac5> in <module>
      3                     validation_data=validation_generator,
      4                     epochs=150,
----> 5                     callbacks=[tensorboard_callback, model_checkpoint_callback])

/tmp/__autograph_generated_file63laq54x.py in tf__ZNCC(true, predict)
     14                 u = (ag__.ld(true) - ag__.ld(x_bar))
     15                 v = (ag__.ld(predict) - ag__.ld(y_bar))
---> 16                 top = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(np).dot, (ag__.ld(u), ag__.ld(v)), None, fscope)
     17                 bottom = (ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(np).linalg.norm, (ag__.ld(u),), None, fscope) * ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(np).linalg.norm, (ag__.ld(v),), None, fscope))
     18                 zncc = (ag__.ld(top) / ag__.ld(bottom))

<__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: in user code:

    File "<ipython-input-136-e4e00382e336>", line 9, in ZNCC  *
        top = np.dot(u,v)
    File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in dot  **
        

    ValueError: shapes (128,3490) and (128,3490) not aligned: 3490 (dim 1) != 128 (dim 0)
```

Could anyone provide the reason for this error and the solution to fix it?

Much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I have tried to reimplement the loss function like so:

```
def ZNCC(true, predict):
  x_bar = tf.math.reduce_mean(true)
  y_bar = tf.math.reduce_mean(predict)
  u = true - x_bar
  v = predict - y_bar
  print(x_bar)
  print(y_bar)
  print(u)
  print(v)
  u = tf.dtypes.cast(u, tf.float64)
  v = tf.dtypes.cast(v, tf.float64)

  top = tf.tensordot(u,v,1)
  bottom = tf.norm(u) * tf.norm(v)
  zncc = top/bottom
  print(top)
  print(bottom)
  print(zncc)
  zncc = tf.cond(tf.less(zncc,0),lambda: tf.dtypes.cast(0, tf.float64), lambda: zncc)
  return 1-zncc
```

Then I have also try to evaluate the function like so:

```
x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = tf.constant([2,2,2,2,1])
ZNCC(x,y)
```

It return the result as follow as expected:

```
tf.Tensor(3, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([-2 -1  0  1  2], shape=(5,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([1 1 1 1 0], shape=(5,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(-2.0, shape=(), dtype=float64)
tf.Tensor(6.324555320336759, shape=(), dtype=float64)
tf.Tensor(-0.31622776601683794, shape=(), dtype=float64)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=1.0>
```

However, when I try to run it as loss function it give the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'ZNCC/Tensordot/MatMul' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 612, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1786, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 758, in _run_callback
      ret = callback()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1233, in inner
      self.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1147, in run
      yielded = self.gen.send(value)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 365, in process_one
      yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 268, in dispatch_shell
      yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 545, in execute_request
      user_expressions, allow_stdin,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 306, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 536, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2855, in run_cell
      raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 68, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3058, in run_cell_async
      interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3249, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-42-c047e0d40ac5>", line 5, in <module>
      callbacks=[tensorboard_callback, model_checkpoint_callback])
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1409, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1040, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 890, in train_step
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 949, in compute_loss
      y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 139, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 243, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "<ipython-input-39-245f12eafcef>", line 9, in ZNCC
      top = tf.tensordot(u,v,1)
Node: 'ZNCC/Tensordot/MatMul'
Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [128,3490], In[1]: [128,3490]
     [[{{node ZNCC/Tensordot/MatMul}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_3878]
```

Comment: First of all, you cannot implement losses using numpy, it has to be with tensorflow functions.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thank you very much. I will try to reimplement it in TensorFlow functions.

Comment: Inside your loss function, everything must be with tensors datatype and tensor operation.

Comment: @Omar Do you mean that all addition, subtraction, multiplication, etc. should be written in the TensorFlow function?

Comment: @SorawitC yes all mathematician operations must be done in tensor operations … check this link https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math